# Windows Kit 8.1 headers have trouble determining WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

In one of the project in my app solution I am getting a compile error:

> ...\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\dlgs.h(245): fatal error RC1017: invalid integer constant expression

Precisely, this is the code thats causing the issue:

```
#if (WINVER >= 0x400) //this line
#define PAGESETUPDLGORD         1546
#define NEWFILEOPENORD          1547
#define PRINTDLGEXORD           1549
#define PAGESETUPDLGORDMOTIF    1550
#define COLORMGMTDLGORD         1551
#define NEWFILEOPENV2ORD        1552
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x400) */
```

Which seems really strange, because in the said project settings, I have set the C/C++ preprocessor definitions:

`WINVER=0x0601;_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601`

Where 0x0601 is the value corresponding to Windows 7, which is the OS I am using.

I have added this sanity check macro to StdAfx.h to determine if preprocesor sees these values correctly:

```
#define XSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x

#pragma message("WINVER equals:") 
#pragma message(XSTR(WINVER))
#pragma message("WIN32_WINNT equals:")
#pragma message(XSTR(_WIN32_WINNT))
```

And during build I am getting proper values:

```
1>StdAfx.cpp  
1>WINVER equals:  
1>0x0601  
1>WIN32_WINNT equals:  
1>0x0601
```

Note that this error happens after directly after cl.exe prints this to console:

> 1>Generating Code...

From my investigation, it seems like the preprocesor WINVER as it's defined without a value, such as:

```
#define WINVER
```

I tried adding the same macro to windows headers but they don't put the pragma message into console somehow. I am running out of ideas. How can this be, what else can I do?

I also tried the stupid solution of manually editing the windows kit headers to redefine WINVER to the 0x0601, but there's many of these headers and this is just a hack to get a job done fast.

Comment: *RC1017* this is *rc.exe* error, not related to *c/c++* at all. what macros you define for *c/c++* here unrelated. show your resorce file instead. are you include *winres.h* ?

Comment: I have somehow missed the fact that this issue is resource compiler related. 
I fixed the issue by also adding these preprocesor definitions to the Project Properties -> Resources -> General -> Preprocessor Definitions. 
My project CMake generated this solution without values due to some error, and there goes the result. Thanks!

Comment: i think that correct solution in your case add *winres.h* to your *rc* file.